# postgresql: procedure to return the number of occurrences of given year and service

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am creating a procedure to return the number of times a given service is done in a year. The procedure cannot return a NULL value. The table I am taking the data from is called "tb_orders" and has "created_dt" and "order_code" as columns; for the datetime the service was provided and the code of the service itself.

So far I've got this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION catalog_yearly_orders
  (year, order_code) RETURNS numeric AS $$
DECLARE
  n_service integer NOT NULL,
  year YEAR(tb_orders.created_dt)%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT order_code INTO order_code
  FROM tb_orders
  WHERE order_code = order_code;
  n_service = n_service + 1;
  RETURN n_service;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think what I am missing is some command, between BEGIN-END, for the parameters to match the tuples I am looking for so that I get the ones which coincide with year and service code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `tb_orders` table has an `id`, would you not be able to do something like the following?

```
RETURN (SELECT COUNT(tbo.id)
          FROM tb_orders tbo
         WHERE YEAR(tbo.created_dt) = year AND tbo.order_code = order_code);
```

In your `DECLARE` you are overwriting the `year` value, and I'm not at all sure what `n_service` is supposed to do. If all you want is a count, then `COUNT()` is all you need. Mind you, using `YEAR()` in the `WHERE` clause is not great, but it's sufficient for the sake of this example.

> **Note:** The syntax may be a bit off. I'm a bit rusty with stored procedures in PostgreSQL.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense than my code, thank you! But I am having trouble with the `year` value. All I get is an error saying: `ERROR:  type year does not exist
SQL state: 42704`

Comment: Use EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_field)?

Comment: I think I solved it. I wasn't properly defining the parameters `year` and `order_code`.